# Pass values between master and detail

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, storyboard

Which do you think the best way to pass data between the two sides of a split view? Which do you think the best way to call a method from master to detail or from detail to master? Protocols? Segues? Or...?

I have seen seem tutorials in this topic but I can not figure out what is the most trivial way of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols are the best way if you need to use them for multiple `UIViewControllers`. Though if you need to explicitly communicate between two controllers, try simply storing a weak reference between them to call methods.