# I want to pass data between two UIViewControllers in my universal app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UISplitViewController Master / Detail communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031238/uisplitviewcontroller-master-detail-communication)

For iPad i am using UISplitViewController,for phone i m using navigation controller,i am unable to find a common way to pass object from master to detail view controller.

Comment: This question is asked many times already. Why not do a search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770587/pass-values-between-master-and-detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031238/uisplitviewcontroller-master-detail-communication

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what's called `Delegation`. Check here for my previous SO Answer and quick example , also includes a Link to Apple's Documentation on Delegates and Data Sources. [Objective C View to Controller Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941177/objective-c-view-to-controller-communication/10941216#10941216)

Hope this helps.